# How to get sum of diferent fields / array values in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Using Elasticsearch 7.9.0
My document looks like this

```
{
  "student": {
    "marks": [
      {
        "sub": 80
      },
      {
        "sub": 90
      },
      {
        "sub": 100
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I need one more field `total_marks` in the response of `GET` API
Something like this

```
{
  "hits": [
    {
      "_index": "abc",
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "blabla",
      "_score": null,
      "_source": {
        "student": {
          "marks": [
            {
              "sub": 80
            },
            {
              "sub": 90
            },
            {
              "sub": 100
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "total_marks": 270
    }
  ]
}
```

I tried using `script_fields`
My query is

```
GET sample/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "total_marks": {
      "script": {
         "source": """double sum = 0.0;
                    for( item in params._source.student.marks)
                    { sum = sum + item.sub }
                    return sum;"""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I got response as

```
{
  "hits": [
    {
      "_index": "abc",
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "blabla",
      "_score": null,
      "_source": {
        "student": {
          "marks": [
            {
              "sub": 80
            },
            {
              "sub": 90
            },
            {
              "sub": 100
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "fields": {
        "total_marks": [
          270
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is thare any way to get as expected?
Any better/optimal solution would be helps a lot.
Thank you.

Comment: scripts are slower. You can use  count aggregation instead

Comment: Okay, but aggregation is to get aggregated values for all the docs in the hits right? I need total marks for each document. Please correct me if I am wrong. and please suggest how to do using count aggregation.

Comment: sorry it should be sum aggregation. If you need it on group by basis, you can add terms aggregation

Comment: is there any unique  field in each document? like  student id etc. based on which a group by can be done

Comment: Yes I have a unique ID. I will try group by with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)  and [sum aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) can be used to find total marks per group

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "students": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "student.id.keyword",
        "size": 10
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_marks": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "student.marks.sub"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Result**

```
"aggregations" : {
    "students" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "1",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "total_marks" : {
            "value" : 270.0
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

This will be faster than script but Pagination will be easier in query as compared to aggregation. So choose accordingly.

Best option may be to have it calculated at index time. If those fields are not changing frequently.

Comment: Yes pagination will be dificult if we do aggrigations. If we do sort on some fields then aggrigations will not be sorted in that order.
Now I am doing calculations at index time. I guess It will reduce the redundant calculations(and cpu usage) as the marks will not be changed later.